# Bootstrap - sticky footer overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use example from Bootstrap:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html

Problem is when text on page is longer then screen resolution (height: 100%) everything under the red line is footer, but "test" is content:

http://postimage.org/image/55l8q3xuz/

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could post your actual code that would help, but there are two common ways this could happen.

1. You have a fixed height on your content and don't have any kind of overflow set
2. The sticky footer has a negative margin, in which case you would want to put a compensating margin on the content.  If you show your code we could help with actual measurements.